# cant get default selected value with index (angular material mat-button-toggle)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

the code is very simple and the toggle button are getting the values from the index but i cant get the value to be default selected
i have tried to set the value of toggle button group to "i" and it did select all the options by default but when i use the actual number that the value should have it dosent work

```
    <mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style" value= 0>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index" value="i">{{category.name}}</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it as expression in value Input:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style" value="0">
  <mat-button-toggle
    *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index"
    value="{{i}}"
    >{{category.name}}</mat-button-toggle
  >
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```